# Wordpress: Trying to use update_option_optionname

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a tracking mechanism to my wordpress plugin. And I want to use the WP cron mechanism. So I have an options page and when users save all options I want to use a hook to remove or add the tracking to the wp cron depending of the admins choice.

But right now I am stuck.

I have:

```
register_setting ( 'my-settings-group', 'myplugin_tracking');

add_action ( 'update_option_myplugin_tracking', 'myplugin_schedule_tracking' );

        function myplugin_schedule_tracking($old_value, $new_value)
        {

             echo "Setting is updated!";
             echo $old_value;
        }
```

But this does not seem to work. I also used:

```
add_filter ( 'update_option_myplugin_tracking', 'myplugin_schedule_tracking' );
```

The option is saved in a form that posts to the options.php if that matters.

What am I doing wrong? Hope somebody can help out as I cannot find much information about doing something upon updating an option!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this seems to work after all.

```
register_setting ( 'my-settings-group', 'myplugin_tracking');

function myplugin_schedule_tracking($old_value, $new_value)
{
    if ($old_value !== $new_value)
    {
        if ($new_value == '')
        {
            wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'myplugin_tracking' );
        }
        elseif ($new_value == 'on' && $current_schedule == FALSE)
        {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'myplugin_tracking' );
        }
    }
}

add_filter ( 'update_option_myplugin_tracking', 'myplugin_schedule_tracking', 10, 2);
add_action ( 'myplugin_tracking', 'myplugin_tracking' );
```

In the function myplugin_tracking you do whatever you have to do to track.

My problem was that I did not see the echo on the screen but it did appear to work after all.

Perhaps not the best code but it may be helpful for others :-)